# another limits.conf question : limit nofiles specifically for a process

Tags: 18.04, startup, autostart

My  /etc/security/limits.conf file looks like this

```
* soft nofile 1024
* hard nofile 2048
couchdb soft nofile 35000
couchdb hard nofile 35000
root soft nofile 65535
root hard nofile 65535
```

I want to have a specific limit for my couchdb process, for root and for the rest.
The above does not work.

How is one supposed ot setup limits for a process (which starts automatically on startup) as opposed to a user ?

Comment: use "control groups" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups )?

Comment: `couchdb` must be either a `user name` or a `group name`. Did you create either a `user` or `group` for `couchdb`? Please report to `@marmayogi`

Comment: I created a group couchdb including the user couchdb in /etc/group and that seemed to have done the trick. thks @Rinzwind. If you want to post as answer i'll validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps anyone, based on the comment from @Rinzwind I added a line in `/etc/group`

```
couchdb:x:10000:couchdb
```

and it did the trick.